# Show HTML in chosen page

Tags: php, html

Here's my code

```
<?php
if (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) != '' || basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) != 'index.php'){
?>
<div class="hr" style="margin-top:25px;"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to hide that DIV part when the page is index.php or simply the http://www.example.com

I have no error and it's not working... why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this out:

```
$bn = basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH));
if (empty($bn) || strcmp($bn,'index.php') !== 0)
{
  // output div
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `parse_url` component. This is what makes-or-breaks the script, since no path specified will make `basename` default to grabbing the domain (or sub-folder).

Comment: Instead of "=== 0" I changed it to "== true" and it worked. Thanks for showing me the path :D

Comment: @Warface [`strcmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) returns integer `0` on an exact match, but because a `0` is a `false` in a condition, we use type-sensitive comparison (`===`). `===true` theoretically shouldn't work... -- **EDIT** oops, you only want occations when it **isn't** the index. That's why. use `!==0` instead. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

add `/` before that

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/index.php'){
```

Comment: And if it's part of a sub-folder, then.... (I'm assuming the OP has a reason for using `basename` over comparing the string regularly).

Comment: Yeah it's in a sub-folder, the reason of the basename... with the "/" it's not working either...

Answer (score 0):

or you'd just need to `change OR || to &&`.. when you asking "if x is not 2, or x is not 3, output div", you're bound to have true at all times... x is either not 2, or it's not 3.